# Removing unengaged subscribers account wide

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, suppressionlist, exclusion-script

I have a data extension created for contacts we have deemed unengaged based on a predefined set of criteria. This data extensions updates once a week through an automation. For example one of the criteria is that a user hasn't logged in to there account in over 6 months. If the user returns and logs in to the account they are automatically removed from the data extension and start receiving communications again. We send all of our campaigns through journey builder.

How can I exclude the members of this data extension from all campaigns (email and SMS) automatically? I know I can add them to a suppression list or create an exclusion script but this would have to be manually added to each individual campaign and any new campaigns that are created; which is a lot of hassle. This also wouldn’t update the list automatically every week.

Another option is to add a where clause to the SQL query for all data extensions we send from but we have hundreds so this would take time. Is there an easier way to do this account wide?

Answer (score 1):

Use an Automation to import them into an Account-wide Auto Suppression list.

Make sure to design it in such a way, that the Automation also clears those that are no longer supposed to be in the automation.

You could consider the process like so:

- Step 1: Empty the Auto-Suppression List
- Step 2: Import Records from the DE